# Spring Data JPA: Parameterize @Query Annotation String, Refactor Two Similar @Query Methods

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

In Spring Data I have 2 very large queries which are essentially identical, but with small differences. I don't want to duplicate the methods for both queries. Suppose I have

**Method 1**

```
@Query(value = ".. " +
      " .. " + 
      //... big query
      "...")
public List<Bean> getResult(@Param("studyId") long studyId);
```

**Method 2**

```
@Query(value = ".. " +
      " .. " + 
      //... big query, after WHERE: 
      " and (:startDate is null or :startDate = '' or r.recall_date >= to_date(cast(:startDate as TEXT) " + 
      "...")
public List<Bean> getResult(@Param("studyId") long studyId, @Param("startDate" String startDate);
```

My goal is:

1) Parameterize the `@Query` string so that it can either take or omit the optional additional WHERE as a sub-string.

2) Somehow refactor the methods so they don't call separate SQL. The only difference is the additional parameter in Method 2.

Is this possible?

Comment: Could you just put the main SQL in a string, have two method signatures, and concatenate the extra SQL to the query on the second method?

Comment: Spring Data won't allow variables inside `@Query`. It only allows constants.

Comment: You can achieve it via JPA Specification.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work

```java
interface ReportTypeRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<ReportType,String> {

    final String report = " select r from ReportType r ";
    final String where = " where r.active=:active ";
    final String sort = " order by r.id asc ";

    @Query(report + sort) // <-- all with sort
    List<ReportType> findByQuery();

    @Query(report + where + sort)  // <-- all with where and sort
    List<ReportType> findByActiveQuery(@Param("active") boolean active);

}
```

Another (probably better) solution is to use `Spring Data JPA` with `Querydsl` or the `JPA 2 Criteria API` where you can define some `Predicates` and combine then to use multiple constraints.

Comment: Are you familiar with Spring Data? Are you aware that `Query` has a `value=` attribute?

Comment: @geneb.Yes, `value` is optional, you only need to use it if you do something like `@Query(
  value = "SELECT * FROM .....", 
  nativeQuery = true)`

Answer (score 0):

You could also take a look on [`Specification`](https://www.baeldung.com/rest-api-search-language-spring-data-specifications) if you plan to do dynamic queries.